# How can we encrypt bytes through DES/CBC/NOPADDING in Objective C?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, encryption

I am trying to encrypt bytes data through DES/CBS/NOPADDING algorithm but unable to get correct output. What I have tried is given below in code. Please have a look and suggest.

```
#import "STEncryptViewController.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import "STEncryptorDES.h"
#import "NSData+Base64.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

#define KEY  @"MY_TEST_KEY"

@interface STEncryptViewController ()

@end


@implementation STEncryptViewController

@synthesize message;
@synthesize encrypted;
@synthesize decrypted;
@synthesize key;
@synthesize outputMessage;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (IBAction)encrypt:(id)sender
{
    const unsigned char bytes[] = {65,17,17,17,17,17,17,17};


    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];

    NSString *str = self.key.text;
    NSData* data12 = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSUInteger len = str.length;
    uint8_t *bytes1 = (uint8_t *)[data12 bytes];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len * 3];
    // [result appendString:@"["];

    //Key convertion
    int i = 0;
    while(i < len){
        if (i) {
            [result appendString:@","];
        }
        [result appendFormat:@"%d", bytes1[i]];
        i++;
    }
    // [result appendString:@"]"];
      NSLog (@"String is %@",str);
      NSLog (@"Byte array is %@",result);

    //

    Byte iv1 [] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    Byte iv [] = {1, 35, 69, 103, -119, -85, -51, -17};
    NSData *ivData = [NSData dataWithBytes:iv length:sizeof(iv)];

    NSData *encryptedData = [STEncryptorDES encryptData1:data key:[NSData dataWithBytes:iv1 length:sizeof(iv1)] iv:ivData];

    NSLog(@"encrypted : %@", [encryptedData base64EncodedString]);
    self.outputMessage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Encrypted String ::>> %@",[encryptedData base64EncodedString]];

    [self doCipher:nil enc:kCCEncrypt];
}
- (NSData *)md5DataFromString:(NSString *)input
{
    const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
}
- (IBAction)decrypt:(id)sender
{
    NSData *valueData = [self hexToBytes:self.decrypted.text];
    NSData *keyData = [self md5DataFromString:self.key.text];
    Byte iv [] = {1, 35, 69, 103, -119, -85, -51, -17};
    NSData *ivData = [NSData dataWithBytes:iv length:sizeof(iv)];
    NSData *decryptedData = [STEncryptorDES decryptData:valueData key:keyData iv:ivData];
    NSLog(@"decrypted : %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    self.outputMessage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decrypted String ::>> %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
}

- (NSString*)doCipher:(NSString*)plainText enc:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt{

    NSData *key123 = [self hexToBytes:@"MY_TEST_KEY"];
    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize;

    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {
        NSData *EncryptData = [self hexToBytes:@"5454545454545454"];

      //  NSData *EncryptData =[NSData  dataWithBase64EncodedString:plainText];
        plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length];
        vplainText = [EncryptData bytes];
    }
    else
    {
        plainTextBufferSize = [plainText length];
        vplainText = (const void *) [plainText UTF8String];
    }


    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t movedBytes = 0;
    //  uint8_t ivkCCBlockSize3DES;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);

    unsigned char cKey[FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];
    bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
    [key123 getBytes:cKey length:FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];


    //unsigned char result1[24]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,00,00,00,0};
    unsigned char IV3[8]={1, 35, 69, 103, -119, -85, -51, -17};

    uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSize3DES];
    memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                       0x0000 ,
                       cKey, //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                       kCCKeySize3DES,
                       IV3 ,  //iv,
                       vplainText,  //plainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       &movedBytes);

    //if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    /*else*/ if (ccStatus == kCCParamError) return @"PARAM ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCBufferTooSmall) return @"BUFFER TOO SMALL";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCMemoryFailure) return @"MEMORY FAILURE";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCAlignmentError) return @"ALIGNMENT";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) return @"DECODE ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCUnimplemented) return @"UNIMPLEMENTED";

    NSString *result;

    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {

        result = [ [NSString alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    }
    else
    {
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
        NSLog(@"data is: %@", myData);
      //  result = [NSData base64StringFromData:myData length:myData.length];
        //  result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        result = nil;
    }


    return result;
}

-(NSData*)hexToBytes:(NSString *)hex {


    NSString *safeStr = [hex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@"A"];

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData data];
    int idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx+2 <= safeStr.length; idx+=2) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(idx, 2);
        NSString* hexStr = [safeStr substringWithRange:range];
        NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStr];
        unsigned int intValue;
        [scanner scanHexInt:&intValue];
        [data appendBytes:&intValue length:1];
    }

    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)data.hash);

    return data;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This was my all effort. Currently it is working but not expected output getting. Please suggest me what am I missing here?

Comment: Add expected encrypted output in hex dump format for the clear input data to the question. Cleanup the code to present only the required code to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One glaring error is that STEncryptorDES is used and is specifies padding but the question states that padding should be used.

Observations:
- You call doCipher with nil and do not use it's return value, delete the unneeded/unused code from the question.
- There is a lot of code to perform a rather simple operation.
- It seems that the test data variable is named `iv1`, use a better name if that is correct.
- DES should not be used for new work, only when necessary to interoperate with existing work, it is not very secure. New work should use AES.
- `@synthesize` has not been needed for several years.

Answer (score -1):

In cryptography "DESede/CBC/NoPadding" use following code might be help for you.

```
Byte iv [] = {1, 35, 69, 103, -119, -85, -51, -17};

NSData *ivData = [NSData dataWithBytes:iv length:sizeof(iv)];

NSData key = ["MY_TEST_KEY" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

char cKey[key.length];
bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
[key getBytes:cKey length:key.length];

// setup iv
char cIv[kCCBlockSizeDES];
bzero(cIv, kCCBlockSizeDES);
if (ivData) {
    [ivData getBytes:cIv length:kCCBlockSizeDES];
}

// setup output buffer
size_t bufferSize = [data length] + kCCBlockSizeDES;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

// do encrypt
size_t encryptedSize = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                                      ccNoPadding,
                                      cKey,
                                      key.length,
                                      cIv,
                                      [data bytes],
                                      [data length],
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize,
                                      &encryptedSize);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {

    resultData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:encryptedSize];
    free(buffer);

} else {
    free(buffer);
    NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to encrypt|CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);

    return nil;
}
```